# Floating Action Button does not responds when it clicked/touched

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I am using a floating action button(FAB) in my application to show Dialogs, everything is worked just fine when I tested my app in Xperia Z with Lopllipop 5.1.1.
However, the problem is when tested my app in ASUS Zenfone 6 with KitKat 4.4.2 and in Xperia C with Jelly Bean 4.2.2, the FAB loaded perfectly but the FAB does not show the Dialogs, seems like it does not responds when I touched it.
For the record, my min sdk version is 16.

What i want to ask is why this is happening? Is there anything wrong with my code, or maybe with the android version or API level?

Please take a look at my code. Here the XML code:

```
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_account"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

and here how I declare and set the listener for the FAB:

```
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   fab = (FloatingActionButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fab);

   ...
   fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showDialog();
            }
   });
   ...
}
```

The thing that made me confused is how it is worked in Xperia Z but it does not worked in ASUS Zenfone 6?

Comment: Turns out the problem is in the XML file I declare the FAB before the listview, by remove the declaration of FAB after the listview, it solved my problem.

Comment: You should really add the above comment as an answer to your own question, since it really is the solution to this problem. I had the same issue, in my case it was a RecyclerView, then the FAB, then a NestedScrollView. Moved the FAB below the NestedScrollView and the touch/click events started working. Good call.

Comment: @Andrew I wish to put my comment as an answer and put the SOLVED mark to my question, but I really don't have a clue how to do that. so sad...

Comment: I guess just manually copy paste the comment text into the Add Answer field. Try that.

Comment: @Andrew god... it is there all along

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem in here is that I declared the FAB before the declaration of listView. Somehow by relocating the declaration of FAB after the the declaration of listView it will solved the problem.
From:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    ...
    .../>
<ListView
    ...
    ...
    .../>
```

To:

```
<ListView
    ...
    ...
    .../>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    ...
    ...
    .../>
```

Just as simple as that.

Comment: When I was using Kotlin Synthetics (and findViewById), I had to put the FAB above the ListView. But now that Kotlin Synthetics was deprecated and I migrated to Android ViewBinding, I had to move the FAB below the ListView for it to work. I was like, what is happening here.

Comment: Man, thank you so much for finding the problem! It worked great for me! This problem made me crazy! I couldn't find the problem. But thanks to you it is solved now!

Answer (score 13):

Programmatically bringing the FAB to front should also work:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.bringToFront();
fab.setOnClickListener... //etc
```

Comment: Yes, it worked, but the question here is why it didn't work on API 19 while it was working on APIs above 19 ??

Answer (score 1):

Just add clickable and focusable and set both to "true" in FAB (floating action button) in xml file

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    />
```

This enable floating button to receive click events and make clickable